# How to obtain a mandatory filter with api-platform?

Tags: api-platform.com

I have this route (api) :

```
http://...../api/v1/know_how_levels
```

This route is working fine. But I would like to add a mandatory filter like this :

```
http://...../api/v1/know_how_levels?member=something
```

How to do that? Can I add some magic annotations in the entity, or some code in an eventSubscriber (and which one)?

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55020369/filter-required-in-api-platform/57266043#57266043

Comment: Merci Thomas. Exactly what I was looking for. I am a very beginner with api-platform.....and I do not think I will go on longer with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter required in Api Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55020369/filter-required-in-api-platform)

Comment: it takes a little getting used to it. But you can develop very rapid when you are beyound that point.

Comment: For the moment I am most productive without api-platform.... The only think I appreciate in it is the swagger generation. But for all the other aspects, for the moment and for me , it is a kind of "gaz factory".